# Blocked Senders list Outlook 2007

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook-2007, spam-prevention

So a bit of a problems has arisen from a user having a load of emails from a particular address being unanswered because they were all appearing in their Junk Email folder in Outlook.  We push a setting globally to not filter emails for junk (as this is done at another stage).  It turns out the address is on the users "Blocked Senders" list.

If a message is filtered as Junk for whatever reason will it be added to teh Blocked Senders list until the user states otherwise?  Or is the Blocked Senders list a purely manual list that requires user input to amend?

Comment: If a message appears in the "Junk" mail and the blocked senders list is empty then the mail server is defining the message location - often found in an Exchange environment with Outlook. If the server isn't doing the filtering then a hosted email server may be changing the header so the email client identifies it as "Junk"... failing that, then, yes, I'd say the client has added to their local black and white lists.

Comment: Looking in to it further all our users are in online mode to exchange (cached mode is disabled).  Looking at the wording of the notice that pops up when going in to "Junk Email" options the filtering is disabled in Online mode.  So as far as I can work out there is no filtering.  Seeming likely that indeed they have inadvertently added an address to the Block list.

Comment: Find a problem client and go to their Blocklist to see what's in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The blocked senders list is a user controlled list - though it is possible to push entries to it centrally.

If there is an entry there, the user has done it.

If Exchange or Outlook move items into junk, they still will not add anything to the blocked senders list.